# Read .txt file for specific values if found then return

Tags: c#

What i am attempting to do is read a .txt file which is structured like:

```
#signup.php|register.php
URL_1
#...
URL_2
```

I am trying to search the source code of a page, if it finds a value from `URL_1` in the source code it will return to me what that value found was.

To read the .txt file i have this so far:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ReadAiFields(string path)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path)) return values;
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string line = lines[i];
            if (line.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                string[] keys = line.Remove(0, 1).Split('|');
                string value = lines[i + 1];
                foreach (string key in keys)
                {
                    if (!values.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        values.Add(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
    }
    return values;
}
```

So in the source code if `signup.php` is found it will return it.

I have started to write:

```
public static string GetUrlStructureFromFile(string inputHtml)
{
    string returnValue = "";
    inputValue = inputHtml.ToLower();
    var values = ReadAiFields(@"LogicFiles\rj-ai-url.txt");
    var foundKey = values.Keys.FirstOrDefault(key => inputHtml.Contains(key));
    if (foundKey != null)
    {
        returnValue = values[foundKey];
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

This return the key `URL_1` but i really need the value, i never wrote the original code which is why i'm unsure, any tips or help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the file is structured as shown… then in the code, if the searched for string IS found… wouldn’t the `URL_?` value be in `lines[i-1]`? I am guessing I am missing something.

Comment: You need to clarify “what” you are looking “for” and if found “what” you want to return. Your comment… _”if it finds a value from URL_1 in the source code it will return to me what that value found was.”_ ? makes no sense. What is the purpose of returning the value you were looking for?